# My JavaScript pop up modal only works on the first row

Tags: javascript, php, html

First question: I have a dynamic table, with edit icon on every row, when pressing the icon a popup modal should show up. But the popup modal only work on the first row. I tried to determine the problem and I think it’s because of the id "open5", that it’s duplicated and only work for one row which is the first row. How can I make it appear on every row?

Second question: how can I use the book id to determine which book going to be updated, when the user press the button on the update modal?

trackingPage.php

```
<!-- dynamic table -->
<div class="container">
    <table class="_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>الغلاف</th>
                <th>العنوان</th>
                <th>المؤلف</th>
                <th>تاريخ البدء</th>
                <th>تاريخ الإنتهاء</th>
                <th>التقدم</th>
                <th width="50px">
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="table_body">
            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `tracking` WHERE `username_tracking`='$_SESSION[username]'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><img style='width:80px; height: 85px; border-radius: 10px; margin: 0.1px;' src="upload/<?php echo $row['cover'] ?>"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["book_name"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["author_name"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["start_date"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["end_date"] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <div class='progress-container'><progress value='<?php echo $row["current_page"] ?>' max='<?php echo $row["page_number"] ?>'></progress></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class='action_container'>
                            <a href='delete_book.php?book_id=" <?php echo $row["book_id"] ?> "' class='danger' onclick='remove_tr(this)'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>

                            <a class='success' id='open5'>
                                <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="modal-container-tracking" id="modal_container5">
    <div class="modal-tracking">
        <form class="book-form" method="post" action="trackingPage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="closeIcon-tracking" id="close5">
                <span class="close-tracking">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modalContent-tracking">
                <h3>تحديثات الكتاب</h3>
                <input type="number" name="current_page" placeholder="عدد الصفحات المقروءة" class="pages" min='1' required />
                <input name="end_date" placeholder='تاريخ الانتهاء' type="date" class="start-date" required />
                <textarea class="review" name="review" placeholder="مراجعة الكتاب"></textarea>
                <button href="" name="update_book" class="bn60" style="text-decoration: none;">حدِّث الكتاب</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    //Popup page 
    const open5 = document.getElementById('open5');
    const modal_container5 = document.getElementById('modal_container5');
    const close5 = document.getElementById('close5');

    open5.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal_container5.classList.add('show');
    });

    close5.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal_container5.classList.remove('show');
    });
    //end of Popup page
</script>
```

This is my DB:

[Users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tENiB.png)

[Tracking table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfxyh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is looking for an element with the ID `open5`, HTML `id`'s should be unique, but your PHP code renders an element with the same ID for every row, ergo the JS code is satisfied when it finds the first element with ID `open5` and therefore all subsequent ones do not get event listeners attached. You have to switch to a class and then attach a listener to each of those links, e.g. something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr .success').forEach(function(el, i, nodeList) {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal_container5.classList.add('show');
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer solved my javascript problem, thanks a lot